# Palikare (En famille, Hector Malot)

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, histoire, grec

L'auteur Hector Malot, dans son œuvre *En famille*, nomme l'âne du personnage principal (Perrine) **Palikare** qui est un mot grec. Je me demande pourquoi l'auteur utilise ce mot (dont je connais la signification).
Est-ce un emploi littéraire  (*palikare* signifie souvent brave en grec) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

À l'époque, le terme désigne un soldat ou mercenaire grec. Voir http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/palikare qui mentionne des usages à peu près contemporains. (Aujourd'hui ce terme est pratiquement inusité.)

C'est une façon tendre et humoristique d'appeler un animal domestique avec un nom militaire.